# What is the best way to copy a set of records from Oracle to SQL Server using code where table and columns are identical?

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, web-services, silverlight

Basic idea is we have our Silverlight application, and need to provide data to third party application when user want to send (export) a record of `T_MainList`

We maintain our data in Oracle and third party's SQL Server, third party people are providing us access to write a stored procedure, and a web service if needed.

Same table schema is maintained on both databases (Oracle and SQL Server), need to copy a record of `T_MAINLIST` on user request and it has other dependent data sublist can have multiple records and each sublist record can have multiple subsublist records

Is serializing data of whole dataset as xml and send them in stored procedure. De-serialized data in stored procedure (on SQL server) and insert data into the appropriate tables good idea?

[image: Same table schema is maintained on two databases, One is Oracle and another is SQL Server, I need to copy a record of T_MAINLIST when user request and it has other dependent data sublist can have multiple records and each sublist record can have multiple subsublist records]

Comment: Data also contains Image, and data size will be around 100MB

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has the possibility to directly connect to another database, see the example for MS SQL server [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31043/conf_sql.htm#CIHGADGB). That should be faster then using xml ex- and import...